# Simple python library for recognition text from image

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

I'm looking for a simple python library for text recognition from images. Images are similar to this:

[image]

The image contains a very pure and simple - one line, numbers and hyphens, but the resolution is low.

I would like something similar (in an ideal):

```
 text = recognize(open('image.png', 'rb').read())
```

Does something similar exists?
Thanks.

**UPD**

I know about pytesser and OCRopus. But as far as I understand they don't support Python 3.x.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used [pytesser](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/). Very easy to learn, and did a great job for me. 
If you don't like this option, search for 'python OCR library'

Comment: Last release - 0.0.1 - in May, 2007. It is developed?

Comment: I guess not, I didn't even noticed when I downloaded it. Anyway, I don't know other options and this was good for me, so its worth a shot

Comment: Updating old thread here, but important info: use pytesseract instead. Pytesser has been renamed and forked.

Answer (score 6):

OCRopus is another easy to learn OCR library for python. It also seems to yield (slightly) better results than pytesser. Here's the [link to its site](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy)