# How to Read text from image using Python 3.*

Tags: python, image, image-processing, text

Is there any way to read text from image using Python 3.*

For Example:
[image: example]

Output: 5544824104

Comment: Use [open-cv](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple python library for recognition text from image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630650/simple-python-library-for-recognition-text-from-image)