# How to convert complex excel table data into contructed data?

Tags: python, excel, machine-learning

I'm confronted with a problem as below and hoping some body could give some advice.
I need to convert a lot of excel tables in different shapes into constructed data, the excel tables are as below.

```
|--------------------|----|----|
|user:Sam            |    |    |
|--------------------|----|----|  
|mail:sam@example.com|    |    |  


|-------|----------------|-----|
|user   |Jack            |     |
|-------|----------------|-----|
|mail   |jack@example.com|     | 
|-------|----------------|-----|


|-------|-----|---------------|---------|
|user   |May  |               |         |
|-------|-----|---------------|---------|
|       |mail |may@example.com|         |
|-------|-----|---------------|---------|


|user   | Alex  |mail  |alex@example.com|
```

The target result would be like the following format.

```
|-------|-------------------|
|user   | email             |
|-------|-------------------|
|Jack   | jack@example.com  |
|-------|-------------------|
|Sam    | sam@example.com   |
|-------|-------------------|
|Alex   | alex@example.com  |
|-------|-------------------|
|May    | may@example.com   |
|-------|-------------------|
```

My current solution is to define a function for each type of excel table. But there would be thousands of different excel files so I would have to repeat write similar code. So my question is whether there is common solution for it.

I found one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32089023/looking-for-a-little-python-machine-learning-advice) about this but there is no more information.I think machine learning may help to solve the problem, but I know little about that. Is there any one who could share some thoughts?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the patterns you have provided in your question we see that the data is sometimes in a separate cell, other times encoded in the text with a ':' separator. I'd flatten it out and parse the assembled text for a linear pattern.

I suggest you read the excel file using something like [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd).
Then step through the cells pulling out the text and parse out the fields you are interested in.

```
<cell>'user'<cell|':'>user_name<cell>'mail'<cell|':'>email_address<cell>
```

where `<cell>` is one or more cell boundaries, possibly spread over rows.

Once you have the user email pairs you can write them out using [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt).

Answer (score -1):

You have 4 types of files.

If that is all you can write 1 function with 4 if statements.

```
def table_sort(file):

    If file == condition:
         extract_data_this_way 

   elif file == other_condition:
        extract_data_this_way

   elif file == other_condition:
        extract_data_this_way

   else:
        extract_data_this_way
```

If you use pandas to do this it will make it a lot easier to code.

I'd you have a lot of files.  You can pass in a list and use a for loop to iterate.   Or use glob to load all excel files in a directory and loop that  way .

Comment: Thist would only fit the 4 example formats. The OP stated that he would have to deal with many more different formats ...

Comment: He said there would be thousands of files and presented what the 4 types were. My solution was adequate for the question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and sorry for my poor description of the question. The condition is that there are many more formats that I don't know for sure. And what's more complicated is that there are other fields in the same table to extract.

Comment: It's no problem.  It only makes the question more interesting.