# How to read a TEXT in an image in PDF extension file using Python?

Tags: python

I have tried reading a PDF file with tabular data with texts and succeed it. But i have an image which is in PDF format and contains some text which need to be fetched for record purpose.All the PDFs are in a specific folder. I know only basics in python.
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630650/simple-python-library-for-recognition-text-from-image

Comment: https://tabula.technology/ this could probably solve your problems using the coordinates of the your particular field you are extracting

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file

Comment: I have tried with pyPDF2 . it recognizes tabular data and texts in pdf which are converted from MS word to PDF but i need to read an image which has some random texts .Can anyone help in that?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the both images (inline & XObject) and texts (plain and containing PDF operators) from PDF document using [pdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/)

Here is a sample code extracting all the above from all document pages.

```
from pdfreader import SimplePDFViewer, PageDoesNotExist

fd = open(you_pdf_file_name, "rb")
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd)

plain_text = ""
pdf_markdown = ""
images = []
try:
    while True:
        viewer.render()
        pdf_markdown += viewer.canvas.text_content
        plain_text += "".join(viewer.canvas.strings)
        images.extend(viewer.canvas.inline_images)
        images.extend(viewer.canvas.images.values())
        viewer.next()
except PageDoesNotExist:
    pass
```

You can also convert images to [PIL/Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) object and save

```
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    img.to_Pillow().save("{}.png".format(i))
```